# How implement auto match of Game Center on iOS

Tags: ios, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

I make the turn-based game on Game Center.
When I search another user through auto-match function, does GameCenter search another user that this game was installed or user that have free time?
Because when I implement auto match feature on turn based game, it returns null value, 
I want to know more detail about the auto match feature.
If GameCenter searches the user that game was installed and the game is not famous, then I think that auto-match can't run.
How can I implement auto-match feature programmatically?
Following codes doesn't return any user of game center.

GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];

```
    request.minPlayers = 2;
    request.maxPlayers = 2;

    [GKTurnBasedMatch findMatchForRequest: request withCompletionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedMatch *match, NSError *error)

     {

         if (match){


             //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GamePlayScene" sender:match];

             NSLog(@"match id: %@", match.matchID);



         }
     }];
```

Because it has very little info on sites for auto-match feature, so please help me for auto-match.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Auto match will work only if someone else who has the game installed is also looking to be automatically matched.

Comment: If then, auto-match feature can't be run on new games? Almost all Game Center users wouldn't install new game, because they don't know the game was maded. The game would be downloaded by few users including the app's author. Does GameCenter search opponent on the users?

Comment: I think you don't understand how auto match works - it is a feature for two or more players who have already installed the game to find other players who want to play the same game together.